how to select worksheet name from cell
I want to select some worksheet name that name worksheet in store in some cell
but, i got error like this
vba error message
here is my vba code
Sub selAct()
Dim loc as string
loc = std.range("B2") 'text that refer my worksheet name 

'error in this code
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(loc.Name).Select

End Sub



I guess std is a codename of a sheet in your workbook. Try ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(loc).Select,
How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

std is not defined, is it a sheet name?  Assuming it's correctandlocis returning a valid string just useThisWorkbook.Sheets(loc).Select(as a side note, you should avoidselecting` at all cost).

@Michal std is a sheet name.
name worksheet is from properties (name). assuming my worksheet name is report, but name properties is data_report. Name worksheet store in sheet std cell B2. i've try this code ThisWorkbook.Sheets(loc).Select but the result is Subscript out of range

@taller std is name sheet sir

Each sheet has two names: a (tab) name and a code name (initially they are the same). In the Project Explorer (VBE-->Crtl+R), it looks like codename (tabname). What does this look like for your sheets e.g. std (Sheet1) and data_report (report)? In the Properties window (VBE-->F4), (Name) is the code name while Name is the tab name. Please clarify e.g. "In the Project Explorer, my names look like this std (Sheet1) and data_report (report). In cell B2 is 'report'".

@VBasic2008 yes sir,
i have two sheets in my workbook. std (std) and report (data_report) and in cell B2 (sheet std) is data_report

Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets(loc).Select shouldn't have raised the Subscript out of range error. Check both, the name and the cell for leading or trailing spaces.

Reference Worksheets By (Tab) Name vs Code Name

Try these two procedures to figure out what is going on.

Sub WorksheetByTabName()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim TabName As String: TabName = std.Range("B2").Value
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(TabName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no worksheet with the (tab) name """ & TabName _
            & """ in workbook """ & wb.Name & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Before selecting a sheet, make sure its workbook is active:
    wb.Activate
    ws.Select

End Sub

Sub WorksheetByCodeName()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim CodeName As String: CodeName = std.Range("B2").Value
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if worksheet doesn't exist
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wb.VBProject.VBComponents(CodeName) _
            .Properties("Name").Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no worksheet with the code name """ & CodeName _
            & """ in workbook """ & wb.Name & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Before selecting a sheet, make sure its workbook is active:
    wb.Activate
    ws.Select

End Sub

